# create connection pool from a class

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

To connect to a database performed:
1.-Create a class conexionX where I place the data connection (no connection pool)
2.-In a DAO class get the Connection from conexionX class, in order to manipulate the database.

My question is how I can do it with the connection pool?

I tried the following, but does not work

PoolConexiones.java

Not a servlet is a normal class

```
package Modelo;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.naming.*;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

public class PoolConexiones extends HttpServlet {

    private  DataSource sourceDb = null;
    private  Connection con=null;
    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.init(config);

        try {
            // recuperamos el contexto inicial y la referencia a la fuente de
            // datos
            Context ctx = new InitialContext();
            sourceDb = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/Practica5");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ServletException(
                    "Imposible recuperar java:comp/env/jdbc/tutoriales", e);
        }
    }

    public  Connection getConnection() {

        try {
            synchronized (sourceDb) {
                con=sourceDb.getConnection();
            }
            if(con==null){
                  throw new ServletException("Problemas con la conexion");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ServletException e) {


    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return con;
}
public void CerraConexion(){

    try {
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Ohh.. Why you are using servlet here ?

Comment: As used in a servlet so, thought I could do it separately

Comment: How to retrieve the connection without using the init function?

Comment: But if you are using a DataSource, it's a ConnectionPool, what are you looking to archive? Why isn't it working? What error are you getting?